# Hybrid graphics in linux

Tags: nvidia, acpi, multi-gpu

I came across Nvidia optimus implementation for linux called bumblebee project https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project
I installed bumblebee on my laptop with Nvidia graphics card. The issue is that for the applications which need to use discrete gpu, have to be run through a special command "Optirun". Hence only when this is done, the discrete gpu is powered on else it is powered off whenever necessary to conserve power.
Is there a way to identity whether an application needs discrete gpu to run or could run on normal on chip graphics processor. Can this be done in linux ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, I also have a laptop with an optimus card, even on windows it has a list of applications you want to run with the nvidia chip or the intel one.

I believe that when you install the driver it comes with a list.

In theory you could profile each application that uses the video card for how much GPU/Memory it uses, if it is more than said limit you tag that this app should run on the nvidia if it is running on nvidia but using a small ammount you tag it to use the intel chip